# bootstrap 3 icon button with svg text align

Tags: html, css, svg, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and some svg icons in my project. The text on the button which is using svg icon is coming on right bottom corner of the button not in the middle of the button.

[image: This is the picture of the button]

the button code is

```
<button class="btn"><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#play-button-1"/></svg>Previous</button>
```

the button css is

```
.btn {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

copy code of icon buttons from a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it without standard bootsrap 3 styles, because there is no BS class  for `vertical-align: middle`

```
<button class="btn"><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#play-button-1"/></svg><span>Previous</span></button>
<!-- some extra span around the text -->
```

and

```
.btn {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn svg, .btn span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **display:grid;** inside **.btn{}**

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display:grid;
  
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#play-button-1"/></svg>Previous</button>
```